# Impossible Cipher v1.0

Tags: cipher

When I create riddles, ciphers etc.. they seem to get solved within only a couple of days of writing. Well no more! This cipher may not be impossible but is extremely difficult. If left unsolved for too long, I shall make it slightly easier but not too much so.

Crack the cipher and tell me what the message is. Good look!

[image]

I know it isn't much to go on. Hints will be posted every 1-3 days.

Hint 1:

> It's a 7-step cipher including substitution ciphers, mathematical operations and other types of cipher

Hint 2:

> TSSBMRSR

Hint 3:

> XUQIOOCG

Hint 4:

> The first step to decrypting it is thanks to Logie Baird

Hint 5:

> TBRNRTGB

Hint 6:

> We also have to thank Julius, Gottfried and Samuel

Hint 7:

> I have already given you all of the operations so you should now be able to solve it!

Comment: Is there meant to be anything here recognizable as ciphertext, or is the idea that "When I create ... not too much so" actually _is_, or contains, the ciphertext?

Comment: No, sorry. I accidentally posted this before I finished the cipher. It'll Be up soon!

Comment: In that case I can tell you: right now, it *is* impossible.

Comment: Haha. Yes. Another 5 mins and I think it'll be up and running!

Comment: Btw I definitely don’t recommend posting hints every 2 weeks, at most I think it should be every couple of days, as in two weeks lots of new stuff will be posted and this may fall behind. General policy is post a hint every 24 hours, but I reckon it could be a bit more, but definitely not 2 weeks :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice i'll do them every few days

Comment: I'd probably say we need a few more explicit hints to solve this, especially where to start. There's only so much you can do with coloured pixels, and having tried everything I could think of I'm very intrigued as to how to solve this, but I feel like there's going to need to be a slighlty explicit hint to get the ball rolling :)